# Use Fermat's Little Theorem to find all the roots of the following

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Am I doing this problem right?

> Use Fermat's Little Theorem to find all the roots of the following polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}[x]$: $2x^{74}-x^{55}+2x+6$

If I know that Fermat's Little Theorem states

> $a^{p-1} \equiv1 \pmod{p} $

Therefore if the if we are using $\mathbb{z}_{7}[x]$ we can use $a^6 \equiv1 \pmod {7}$

Which will allow for: $$2(x^{74})-(x^{55})+2x+6=$$
$$2\Big(x^{(6*12)=72}\equiv 1 \pmod{7}\Big)x^2-\Big(x^{(6*9)=54} \equiv 1 \pmod 7\Big)x+2x+6=$$
$$2x^2-x+2x+6=2x^2+x+6$$

Am I doing this right ? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Looks great so far. To see how that final quadratic factors, you might want to write the middle term as $8x$ instead of $x$.

Comment: You need also to consider $x=0$ to eliminate the possibility.

Comment: That's a good point. FLT doesn't apply if $x\equiv 0$, but that's easy to rule out, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that $0$ is not a root. If $a\ne0$ is a root, then
$$
a^{74}=a^{6\cdot12+2}=a^2,
\qquad
a^{55}=a^{6\cdot9+1}=a
$$
and therefore $2a^2-a+2a+6=0$ or $2a^2+a-1=0$; the quadratic formula gives…